# Declare C# exception with .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net-standard

This question looks too rookie but I wasn't able to google answer within 15 minutes.

I am trying to create class library for **.net Standard** and stuck with exception definition.

I am using well-known **Exception** snippet which generates following code:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class MyException : Exception
    {
        public MyException() { }
        public MyException(string message) : base(message) { }
        public MyException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
        protected MyException(
          SerializationInfo info,
          StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
    }
```

However, during compilation I am getting errors:

```
1>Exceptions\MyException.cs(2,22,2,35): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Serialization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
1>Exceptions\MyException.cs(7,6,7,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SerializableAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>Exceptions\MyException.cs(7,6,7,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Serializable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>Exceptions\MyException.cs(14,11,14,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SerializationInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>Exceptions\MyException.cs(15,11,15,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StreamingContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.7) dotnet standard has SerializationAttribute. 
Do I need to install something specific to target dotnet standard 1.2?

Comment: Do you have the correct `using` statements at the top of the file?

Comment: using System;
Should be good enough for System.Serializable​Attribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SerializableAttribute` is [included in .NET Standard 2.0](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.SerializableAttribute), not 1.2.

Comment: Ok, where I can get one? 
I am surprised that VS 2017 haven't install it by default